# Using memset to clear base class members

Tags: c++

I see code like below and don’t like it. Especially memset(static_cast(this), 0, sizeof(BaseStruct));
I need arguments for refactoring and found one here: [Why can it be dangerous to use this POD struct as a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113422/why-can-it-be-dangerous-to-use-this-pod-struct-as-a-base-class)

Do you see more problems? Is vtable in danger?

```
// abstract class
class BaseA {
public:
    virtual void doSomethingA() = 0;
};

// no method, no virtual method, only simple data
typedef struct BaseStruct {
    int x;
    float y;
    long z[10];
} BaseStruct;

class Subclass : public BaseA, public BaseStruct {
public:
    virtual void doSomethingA() {}
    virtual void doSomethingElse() {}
    void resetBaseA() {
        memset(static_cast<BaseStruct*>(this), 0, sizeof(BaseStruct));
    }
};
```

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. Nothing more needs to be said to justify binning the whole thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty derived optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838292/empty-derived-optimization)

Comment: Replace the `memset` with `*this = BaseStruct();` or, in C++11, `static_cast<BaseStruct>(*this) = {};`. Zeroing without the nasty undefined behavior.

Comment: Here are some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38103250/3223828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BaseStruct has no virtual member, so you should be good. vtbl should be for BaseA. However, better would be if could reset each individual member explicitly. That's recommended.